# ESlint fails in Github Actions but works locally

Tags: typescript, github-actions, typescript-eslint

I have a Node TypeScript project with 2 main subdirectories: `/client` and `/server`. Currently, the `/client` folder is empty.

Linting the `/server` folder works fine locally. However, it fails when trying to lint in Github Actions and I get the following error:

```
/home/runner/work/ladybug-2.0/ladybug-2.0/server/index.ts
  0:0  error  Parsing error: Cannot read file '/home/runner/work/ladybug-2.0/ladybug-2.0/server/tsconfig.json'

/home/runner/work/ladybug-2.0/ladybug-2.0/server/tests/ping.test.ts
  0:0  error  Parsing error: Cannot read file '/home/runner/work/ladybug-2.0/ladybug-2.0/server/tsconfig.json'

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I've tried the following:

- setting up a .vscode folder and manually adding in `/client` and `/server` to `settings.json` like so:

```
    {
      "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        "client",
        "server"
      ]
    }
```

- updating the eslint config file to use `__dirname` as the `tsconfigRootDir` property in the `parserOptions` object, but this then throws up another error in index.ts where it says:

  Parsing error: Cannot read file '/users/[user_name]/coding/projects/ladybug-2.0/tsconfig.json'

If I don't set the `tsconfigRootDir` property, then the error disappears from `index.ts`.

Here's my package.json, github actions and eslint config files for reference:
**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev index.ts",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts .",
    "tidy": "npx prettier . --write",
    "start": "node build/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@flydotio/dockerfile": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.9",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@types/validator": "^13.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.5",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

**deployment.yaml**
name: Deployment pipeline

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  lint_and_tidy_server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16'

      - name: Lint and Tidy Server
        working-directory: ./server
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run lint
          npm run tidy
```

**eslint config file**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/semi": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }
    ],
    "no-case-declarations": "off"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "tsconfig.json",
    "sourceType": "module"
  }
}
```

What steps can I take to troubleshoot or resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: When you specify `working-directory: ./server` does that mean the `npm install ` and `npm run lint` commands happen inside that `./server` directory?  If so, is that what you want to happen? Also, are the paths to the `tsconfig.json` file in the error message the paths you expect?

Comment: These commands should take place in `./server` and the error message resolves to the `tsconfig.json`. So not sure what's causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

We recommend setting `parserOptions.tsconfigRootDir` so that the tooling can understand where your ESLint config file is in relation to your workspace.

https://typescript-eslint.io/packages/parser#tsconfigrootdir

Checkout the docs on setting up type-aware linting:

https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/typed-linting